# Pure Python Implementation of gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have tried to implement gradient descent myself using Python. I know there are similar topics on this, but for my attempt, my guess slope can always get really close to the real slope, but the guess intercept never matched or even come close to the real intercept. Does anyone know why is that happening?

Also, I read a lot of gradient descent post and formula, it says for each iteration, I need to multiply the gradient by the negative learning rate and repeat until it converges. As you can see in my implementation below, my gradient descent only works when I multiply the learning rate to the gradient and not by -1. Why is that? Did I understand the gradient descent wrong or is my implementation wrong? (The exam_m and exam_b will quickly go overflow if I multiply the learning rate and gradient by -1)

```
intercept = -5
slope = -4


x = []
y = []
for i in range(0, 100):
    x.append(i/300)
    y.append((i * slope + intercept)/300)

learning_rate = 0.005
# y = mx + b 
# m is slope, b is y-intercept

exam_m = 100
exam_b = 100

#iteration
#My error function is sum all (y - guess) ^2
for _ in range(20000):
    gradient_m = 0
    gradient_b = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        gradient_m += (y[i] - exam_m * x[i] - exam_b) * x[i]
        gradient_b += (y[i] - exam_m * x[i] - exam_b)
        #why not gradient_m -= (y[i] - exam_m * x[i] - exam_b) * x[i] like what it said in the gradient descent formula

    exam_m += learning_rate * gradient_m
    exam_b += learning_rate * gradient_b
    print(exam_m, exam_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for overflow is the missing factor `(2/n)`. I have broadly shown the use of negative signs for more clarification.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intercept = -5
slope = -4
# y = mx + b

x = []
y = []

for i in range(0, 100):
    x.append(i/300)
    y.append((i * slope + intercept)/300)

n = len(x)
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

learning_rate = 0.05
exam_m = 0
exam_b = 0
epochs = 1000

for _ in range(epochs):
    gradient_m = 0
    gradient_b = 0
    for i in range(n):
        gradient_m -= (y[i] - exam_m * x[i] - exam_b) * x[i]
        gradient_b -= (y[i] - exam_m * x[i] - exam_b)

    exam_m = exam_m - (2/n)*learning_rate * gradient_m
    exam_b = exam_b - (2/n)*learning_rate * gradient_b

print('Slope, Intercept: ', exam_m, exam_b)

y_pred = exam_m*x + exam_b
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.plot(x, y_pred, '--', color='black', label='predicted_line')
plt.plot(x, y, '--', color='blue', label='orginal_line')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:
`Slope, Intercept:  -2.421033215481844 -0.2795651072061604`

[image]

Comment: isn't 2/n just some constant and we can use learning rate to substitute it? Also it only go overflow when I multiply by -1. If I don't multiply by -1, all the time my model can get the slope right, but just not the intercept

Comment: In general, if someone implements linear regression there is this factor, so if you report your finding by adjusting learning rate without this factor and someone else tries to implement what you were doing but with the factor, will get different results. If it solves your query do upvote.

Comment: ok thanks. But one more question, do you know why my ML model can never get the intercept right? Is it because of my learning rate or is there something else that I didn't pay attention to

Comment: It depends on the function, also by tweaking learning rate you can get close, but in the end it is still trying to approximate a function, for higher-order functions ML is the best way to get good approximations.